# Why does an error occur saying st.session_state has no key "new_todo" in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit, keyerror

I am following a course and which created this program (The course was Python Mega Course: Learn Python in 60 days, Build 20 apps). When I run the program using streamlit run web.py it says I didn't initialize a key. I thought I did in line 17

web.py

> 

```
import streamlit as st
import functions
todos = functions.get_todos()

def add_todo():
    todo = st.session_state["todo"]
    print(todo)

st.title("My Todo App")
st.subheader("This is my Todo App")
st.write("This app is to increase your productivity.")

for todo in todos:
    st.checkbox(todo)

st.text_input(label="", placeholder="Add New Todo...",
          on_change=add_todo(), key ='todo')
```

Functions.py

> FILEPATH = "todos.txt"

```
def get_todos(filepath=FILEPATH):
    """ Return Contents of File in List"""
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_local:
        todos_local = file_local.readlines()
    return todos_local


def write_todos(todos_arg, filepath=FILEPATH):
    """Write a To-Do in Text File."""
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(todos_arg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello")
```

I have relaunched the app. I have also tried renaming the key and moving the function lower in the code in case it couldn't detect the key.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: KeyError: 'st.session_state has no key "todo". Did you forget to initialize it? More info: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state#initialization'

Answer (score 1):

I happen to follow the same course and encounter exactly the same error like you described. After a lot of trial and error, I noticed that the issue lies in the "on_change" argument in the web.py file:

```
st.text_input(label="", placeholder="Add New Todo...",
          on_change=add_todo(), key ='todo')
```

Try removing the '()' from the "add_todo' function name on that line. It worked for me as I stopped encountering the error after doing that.

Sorry that I'm unable to provide more satisfactory technical explanation. The examples shown in the following Streamlit documentation is what gave me the idea.

https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state